# EaselJS : g is undefined

Tags: javascript, movieclip, easeljs, createjs, flash-javascript-api

The website I have developed uses flash animations exported via easel-js.

URL : http://sm-apps.com/agevent/index-en.html

Browsers Effected : Firefox(quite frequent), Chrome(1st load).
[{Specially Firefox Developer Edition}](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/developer/)

Error : **TypeError: g is undefined** 
(on 1st load in chrome/ Very random for firefox)

File : http://code.createjs.com/easeljs-0.7.0.min.js

1. All the createJS exports are inside the file http://sm-apps.com/agevent/js/createJSExports.js .
2. I m using **PxLoader** to pre-load the images before calling up the init function of createJS . Once All the images are loaded, the PxLoader calls **addCompletionListener** function, which, then calls all the init function. ( file URL : http://sm-apps.com/agevent/js/script.js )
3. **checkState** function(inside addCompletionListener function) then calls the **transitionPage** function (same file as above) which adds the ticker.

> createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", stageHome);

On consecutive loads,(and reloads), i do not get this error! This error is very random and comes usually when we clear our cache or we are loading the website for the 1st time in browser.

I tried : 
1. using the individual createJS exports,instead of one file (commented in html code).did not work.
2. Using *createjs* & *movieclip*(since createJS does not have *movieclip*) instead of *easeljs,tweenjs,movieclip,preloadjs*.did not work.
3.Inerted the PxLoader in html page instead of script.js. Did not work.

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Try subbing out this version instead: http://code.createjs.com/createjs-2013.09.25.combined.js -- This is a combined version of CreateJS, using EaselJS 0.7.0, etc. This should at least give you a better error.

Comment: Thanks Lanny, I have made a combined version of the same, but not sure i m getting some errors!!), Namespace issues?Not sure. As i have exported the <canvas> using flash.
Here is URL 

http://sm-apps.com/agevent/index-en-combined-1.html

Comment: You will need to also include MovieClip -- The version you sent throws an error that it is not defined. It is not part of the combined lib.

Comment: Thanks Lenny. I have already included the movieClip file below the createjs combined file. It still throws an error. The file it throws an error contains all the createJS exports from flash.

Comment: Can you post an updated sample?

Comment: Hello Lanny. Thanks for the replies!, I have updated url...now the error is "o is undefined" . (the issue is prominent specially on FF Developer edition/ First load)

Comment: The error you are seeing is *very likely* related to adding a listener with a handler that is not defined, or not a function. [EDIT: Found the link in the comments. Looking now]

Answer (score 0):

I dug into the source code found here: http://sm-apps.com/agevent/index-en-combined-1.html?page=homePage

The error I am seeing is caused by adding a listener to the Ticker that is `undefined`. This is in scripts.js, line 9538.

```
createjs.Ticker.addEventListener('tick', stageHome);
```

I don't know why this isn't consistent across browsers. I had it come up in the Firefox Developer version.

Maybe this info can help you solve the problem.

Comment: Hey Lanny.
Thanks for the replies and answers.
The stageHome is defined before on line no. 545 on /index-en-combined-1.html page. the call to script.js is made afterwards on line no 711.
now as you can see i have modified the scirpt.js a bit and have included the loading of images in "$(window).load(function() { " function.  The ticker function is called only after all images are loaded ( loader.addCompletionListener(function(e) { function ). BUt issue still prevails.